# Can Google flogger be configured to omit CONTEXT from being included in log

Tags: java, logging, fluent

We are using the rate limiting support in FluentLogger and this is resulting in spurious output being included with our log messages

> messages have been saved destined for corp [CONTEXT ratelimit_period="30 SECONDS [skipped: 6]" ]

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

In general I would not advise turning off the context segment altogether (some code in libraries you don't control may want to provide useful data using it).

There is, internal to Google, a customizable formatter which I think would do what you want. You could trying raising an issue and asking them to open-source it (I no longer work at Google so cannot help directly).

Failing that, it's not actually that difficult to replace the default backend with an alternative, which uses a different "MetadataProcessor" and can be configured to ignore certain metadata keys.

If you are using the JDK backend, you would be able to easily replace `SimpleBackendFactory` and have your own version of `SimpleLoggerBackend` and `SimpleLogRecord` to go with it.

In your version of `SimpleLogRecord` you would overload the method:

```
  protected LogMessageFormatter getLogMessageFormatter()
```

And return a customized formatter.

I would start by looking at the following method in `SimpleMessageFormatter`:

```
public static LogMessageFormatter getSimpleFormatterIgnoring(MetadataKey<?>... extraIgnoredKeys)
```

Which you can pass a list of keys you want ignored (in your case the keys are in `LogContext.Keys.XXX`)

When I wrote Flogger I always envisaged people would want to make their own customized backends, so rather than attempt to add hundreds of flags and options to customize things, I made a lot of helper classes and made it easy to replace the default (simple) backend implementation(s) if they don't suit your needs.